# Django Gmail SMTPAuthentication error

Tags: django, gmail

I recently returned to a django project that used to send email using my gmail account.  Now it doesn't work.  This link:
[Django SMTPAuthenticationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697565/django-smtpauthenticationerror) suggest turning on the less secure authentication, but that seems like its a bad idea.  Is there a new way to do this with the newer google authentication

django 1.6, ubuntu 14.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to create an Application specific password. There is a good answer (not the accepted one) here: 
[Django sending email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914687/django-sending-email)