# send_email not working in django?

Tags: python, django

I wrote a application to send a mail through django

models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django import forms

class EmailForm(forms.Form):

      firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

      lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

      email = forms.EmailField()

      subject = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

      botcheck = forms.CharField(max_length=5)

      message = forms.CharField()
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError

from models import EmailForm

from django.shortcuts import render

def sendmail(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = EmailForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        firstname = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
        lastname = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        botcheck = form.cleaned_data['botcheck'].lower()
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        if botcheck == 'yes':
         try:
            fullemail = firstname + " " + lastname + " " + "<" + email + ">"
            send_mail(subject, message, email, ['myemail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/email/thankyou/')
         except:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/email/')
        else:
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/email/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/email/')
```

when the

`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`

it displaying in the console.

but when the

`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'`

it not sending the email to the specified user.
 my settings.py file

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_USE_TLS   = True
EMAIL_HOST      =  'localhost'

EMAIL_PORT      = '8000'
```

how I can send the email?

Comment: Consider trying to produce [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thank you.i will try.if i dnt specify clearly how others understand?

Comment: help me how to solve it.

Comment: @susmitha if you didn't specified the smtp server at all then how the email will reach inbox ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367014/how-to-send-email-via-django).

Comment: can u please explain in detail what to change in code?

Comment: i have specified the smtp.gmail.com. i also tried it in that way but not worked.

Comment: EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS   = True
EMAIL_HOST      =  'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT      = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django SMTPAuthenticationError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697565/django-smtpauthenticationerror)

Comment: Never, ever, ever use a blank except. Something is going wrong here but that is preventing you from seeing what. Remove that whole try/except and let Django trek you what is going wrong.

Comment: it is giving       SMTPAuthenticationError

Answer (score 4):

You have specified your EMAIL HOST as `localhost` change it to a reliable email host like gmail. Your settings.py can have the below given settings to send emails using gmail smtp server. You have to change the port too.

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True 
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

If issues persists you have to allow `less secure apps` to access your gmail account. This is a recent change that gmail made to their account access policies. By default only a qualified domain can send emails using gmail authentication (`OAUTH2`) mechanism. To allow less secure apps to access your gmail account you have to sign in to google developer console.

Comment: SMTPAuthenticationError

Comment: Goto gmail.com and verify that you can login to gmail using credentials provided in settings.py. Also try to explain question in a fair way with error trace while posting in SO.

Comment: i can login to my account.that only i have mentioned there.

Comment: I have edited above answer. You can refer to that and enable gmail for less secure apps.

Comment: i tried that also by allowing less secure apps in google account settings.but still not working.thank you