# Django Mailer not finding server

Tags: python, django, django-mailer

I'm trying to send an email through Django's wrapper.

Here are my relevant settings.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

EMAIL_PORT = 587

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

The Email, which I am trying to isolate in the most basic form of a view:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def index(request):

    subject = 'Subject'
    message = 'message'
    from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL

    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['email@example.com'])

    return render(request, "index.html")
```

All of the emails and password are legitimate.  When I execute the code, I get thrown an error message:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /....*Link to sign into my account*
Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again
```

I did that but continue to get the same message.  The password I give in the app is correct.  Is there anything I need to configure in my gmail account?

Comment: The return render(...) line is incorrectly indented as displayed and won't be returned as part of the index function. Is this the same indentation you have in your file?

Comment: The return render line was int the correct place in my file, just a typo on the question.

Comment: In my settings I have to set EMAIL_PORT = 587 in order to send through Gmail w/ TLS; the ports available from Gmail as I understand are 25 for no-encryption, 465 for SSL, 587 for TLS

Comment: Any luck? If so, I'll update my answer so that it clearly answers the question as asked now

Comment: That helps! I updated my question as I'm running into another issue.

Comment: Probably best to ask a brand new question; your StackOverflow questions may be viewed by thousands of users years down the line :)

Comment: But... Take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697565/django-smtpauthenticationerror

Comment: That ties things up.  Thanks for your help! I'll clean up by question a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: No problem; blast out some emails and please mark any comments that you found particularly useful as helpful/upvoted. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com '` to`EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'` and I bet your problem will disappear :)

**EDIT #1**
You are running into authentication issues as `EMAIL_USE_TLS` is `True` and Gmail only requires TLS connections for SMTP on port 587. Change to `EMAIL_PORT = 587` and you should bypass the issue.

**EDIT #2**
The error you see can be fixed through your Gmail settings. See - 
[Django SMTPAuthenticationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697565/django-smtpauthenticationerror)

Comment: Sorry for wasting you time with the typo.  That got rid of the error message, but takes me back to a problem I was having earlier before the typo.  When I try to send the email the browser just reloads forever. @Ian Price

Comment: `send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['email@example.com'])` would typically only be called in a view or triggered by a method on a model or form. If you post a new question with the full code where the `send_mail` function is called, we can help you out. And if I helped you out, please mark as complete. Thanks!

Comment: I just had to wait a second before it would allow me to accept the answer.  The function is called in a view that is functional without the mail-related code.@Ian Price