# Sending email with Django, SMTPAuthenticationerror

Tags: django, smtp, django-views, django-settings

I'm trying to send emails in my Django project, but I have some problems. I've found many similar questions, but I couldn't cope with the problem. Could you please tell me what I need to do to be able to send emails. 
This is a part of settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

This is my function from views.py:

```
def add_comment(request, wish_list_id):
wish_list = get_object_or_404(Wish_list, pk=wish_list_id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Comment_to_wish_listForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        newform=form.save(commit=False)
        newform.person = request.user
        newform.comment_to = wish_list
        newform.save()
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        send_mail(
            'New comment',
            cd['text'],
            'fromexample@gmail.com',
            ['toexample@gmail.com'],
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('friends_plans:comment', args=(wish_list.id,)))
    else:
        print form.errors
else:
    form = Comment_to_wish_listForm()
context_dict = {'form': form, 'wish_list': wish_list}
return render(request, 'friends_plans/add_comment.html', context_dict)
```

I get the error SMTPAuthenticationerror (535,Username and Password not accepted). And the same mistake when I use shell commands. I also tried to use Sendgrid as it is advised in some cases, but I get the same mistake.

I followed the link [Django SMTPAuthenticationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697565/django-smtpauthenticationerror) and make the steps as it is advised:
1. I followed the link and allowed access to my Google account.
2. And i choose 'turn on' for 'Access for less secure apps'.
But this didn't help, I have the same mistake!

Comment: That error is self explainatory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django SMTPAuthenticationError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697565/django-smtpauthenticationerror)