# SMTPAuthenticationError - django

Tags: django

I already visit that web-page:
[Django SMTPAuthenticationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697565/django-smtpauthenticationerror)
And i down the "securty captcha" and the "Less secure apps" and still - its giving me that messege:

> SMTPAuthenticationError at /showname/

Here is my view code:

```
def SignUp(request):
    form2 = EmailForm(request.POST)
    if form2.is_valid():
        send_mail(
            form2.cleaned_data['subject'],
            'fffffffffffffwdvedfvedfved',
            form2.cleaned_data['from_email'],
            ['michael.michaelbuzorgi@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

what can i do else to availabe the option of sending mails?

Comment: Try using your actual email address instead of taking `from_email` from the form.

Comment: @Alasdair The problem fixed by reducing more security.