# Send email from gmail with Django and Python

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, gmail

I found a lot of posts regarding send email with django, but I've a specific problem with gmail:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlliO.png)

here are my settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "myemail@gmail.com"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

and my view is:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, send_mail

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name','')
        email = request.POST.get('email','')
        subject = request.POST.get('subject','')
        text = request.POST.get('text','')

        message = 'From: ' + email + '\n\n\n' + text

        send_mail(subject, message, 'myemail@gmail.com', ['myemail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Can you please tell me why I get this error?
I also checked for google settings like "access from less secure applications" and similar

thank you in advance!!!

**edit**

I've already allowed less secure apps and clicked on unlock captcha

Comment: already answered [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697565/django-smtpauthenticationerror](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697565/django-smtpauthenticationerror)

Comment: it did not help. I've already done it... but the problem continues to be

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also.

```
import smtplib

def send_mail(request):
    try:
        subject = "Email Subject"
        description ="description"

        gmail_user =  "from@gmail.com" # email id from where you want send mail
        gmail_pwd ="password"
        FROM = 'Admin: <from@gmail.com>'
        TO = "to@gmail.com" #email id where you want send mail
        TEXT = description
        SUBJECT = subject
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL()
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()

        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
        message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
        server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        server.quit()    
    except Exception,e:
        print 'exception',e
```

Answer (score 0):

hi please check add email id without the gmail extentio ie

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "myemail"
```