# django's email library not working on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am using djangos's send_email function for sending emails to users. Below are my settings.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password+' 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

This is working fine on local this error env but not on heroku.
It is showing:
 `SMTPAuthenticationError`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django SMTPAuthenticationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697565/django-smtpauthenticationerror)

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: I tend to use a 3rd party sender like SparkPost (https://www.sparkpost.com/)

Comment: @DevenderShekhawat under your google account have you selected the setting to "allow less secure app access"?