# Sending emails on Django using SMTP and Gmail

Tags: django, smtp, gmail

I have the following problem with gmail and smtp, i allowed access to less secure apps on my gmail account and i'm able to send emails on my local computer, however when i try to send emails on the remote server that's hosting my application i keep getting SMTPAuthenticationError. I'm not sure what else do i need to do in order for this to work both locally and on the remote server. Anybody have any ideas?

I'm using Django 1.11.15 and Python 2.7.

These are the settings i have on my application:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"

EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER = "myemail@gmail.com"

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mypassword"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is your gmail's login password? Visit https://myaccount.google.com/security, On the left navigation panel, click **Security**. In **Signing in to Google panel**, click **App passwords**, to get a password. It work for me.

If it not work, check [Django SMTPAuthenticationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697565/django-smtpauthenticationerror).

Comment: I noticed my Django app stopped sending emails, and it was this exactly. Thanks much!