# django not sending mail even if password is wrong its showing email sended

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have been struggling to solve this for the last 3 hours but couldn't find it. My problem is that Django is not sending email and even if I enter the wrong username and password it shows successful .It never sends mail. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.Here is my settings.py file

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '******************'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
```

My urls.py file:
`path('reset_password_complete',auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),name='password_reset_complete'), path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'), path('reset_password_sent/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),name='password_reset_done'), path('reset_password/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),name="reset_password"),`

I am using the default view of Django but even if my password is wrong or username is wrong it shows me email has been sent but it has not.Please help me.

Comment: And i have also allowed 'allow less secure apps' on my account

Comment: but it still doesn't work

Comment: It seems to me there is a problem in my settings.py file as even if I don't put  these lines
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '******************'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'

It works as usual

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed the instructions mentioned in the following two answers:

[Django sending email with google SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301868/django-sending-email-with-google-smtp)

[Sending emails on Django using SMTP and Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886042/sending-emails-on-django-using-smtp-and-gmail)

If you are still facing problems and you're on a tight timeline, I would recommend using [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/)'s free plan and then add this to your settings.py file:

```
# settings.py

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'YourAPIKey'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'YourHostPassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'example@mai.com' # the email that you used on SendGrid
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the fast reply.I was just observing that my seetings.py isn't detecting 
what I wrote in it.Is there something I am doing wrong.Here is all the cde that I have entered in my settings.py till now.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '********'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'

Comment: is it something that i have wirite first or or something like that.I am relatively new to django.But I will surely try your way

Comment: I just want to say whether I add those line to not my app is still working the same

Comment: Are you using [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)?

Comment: No , i am using django 3.1.4

Comment: I would recommend adding [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) to your project and doing more research on authentication in Django.