# I get AttributeError while sending Email with Python

Tags: python, email

I am trying to send an email with Python. But I'm having a bug. 
This is my code:

```
import smtplib


def sendmail(subject, body):
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login("....@gmail.com", PASSWORD)
    message_body = f"Subject:{subject}\n\n{body}"
    smtp.sendmail("...@gmail.com", "....@gmail.com", message_body)
    smtp.quit()

sendmail("test subject", "test body")
```

I however get the below bug:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-2157e2df08d1> in <module>
     10     smtp.quit()
     11 
---> 12 sendmail("test subject", "test body")

Comment: Maybe your method names are conflicting. sendmail method is already defined in smtplib. Try changing your method name.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by script name

Comment: I mean file name. Is it by chance email.py?

Comment: It is not email.py

Comment: I tried your code it worked fine on my computer. Have your tried stepping through in a debugger? Is PASSWORD defined as a string?

Comment: PASSWORD is not defined as a string. Stepping through in a debugger?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: PASSWORD should be a string containing your password. That maybe the cause of your issue. Try setting PASSWORD above the function and see if that works.

Comment: The password was set to a string but I'm getting the bug - Username and password not accepted.

Comment: Now that you are sending the username and password properly, it looks like Google is blocking the attempt to login to your account from a less secure source. Follow the instructions here to enable access: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512592/login-credentials-not-working-with-gmail-smtp

Comment: It worked! After turning on less secure apps and putting my password in a string. Thanks a lot jignatius

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
smtp.sendmail(sender, recipient, message_body.as_string())
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#SMTP.sendmail)

`msg` may be a string containing characters in the ASCII range, or a byte string. A string is encoded to bytes using the ascii codec, and lone \r and \n characters are converted to \r\n characters. A byte string is not modified.

```
  smtp.sendmail(sender, recipient, str(message_body))
```