# SMTPAuthenticationError at /email/signup/ in my django project on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Django sendmail is not working, I'm getting this error:

> (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials q13sm252028qtx.80 - gsmtp')

There are similar question on S.O.,like [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512592/login-credentials-not-working-with-gmail-smtp)  everyone taking about "allow less secure apps", but I already turn that option ON. My auth details are correct, I had tried with two different accounts. Two step verification is disabled.

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

views.py

```
def sendmail(email,token):
    subject = 'Verify Email'
    message = 'Hello User please activate your account by click on this link '+'http://mywebsite.pythonanywhere.com/email/verify/'+token
    from_email = 'praveexxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
    recipient_list = [email]
    send_mail(subject=subject,message=message,from_email=from_email,recipient_list=recipient_list)

def signup(request):
    token = generatedtoken
    email = someoneemail@gmail.com
    sendmail(email,token)
```

Comment: Take a look at app-specific passwords https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/GmailAppSpecificPasswords

Comment: Did you try logging in from a browser using same authentication credentials?, Try logging in from an incognito window.