# Django Gmail auth fails despite correct credentials

Tags: django, authentication, gmail

My sending mail from django through gmail suddenly *stopped* working. It was working fine for over a year now, so I assume my basic setup should still be fine. The Google Account in question has 2FA *enabled* and the password used in the config below is a generated *app-password*, not the main accuont password. I already logged into Gmail via browser and checked that it hasn't been locked and that it isn't over quota.

`settings.py`

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<MY-MAIL-ADDRESS>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<PASSWORD>'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '<MY-MAIL-ADDRESS>'
```

I already verified my credentials by using the command below: (ofc shell expansion doesn't work i just pasted the output of the command at that location)

```
$ openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls smtp
>AUTH PLAIN $(echo -ne '\0MY-MAIL-ADDRESS\0PASSWORD' | base64)
>235 2.7.0 Accepted
```

However, if I try to use `send_mail` it bounces:

```
In [1]: from django.core.mail import send_mail                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                         
In [2]: send_mail('Subject', 'This is a test message', 'MY-MAIL-ADDRESS', ('recipient@address.com',))  
 (Output shortened)
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials r17sm9826202wmq.5 - gsmtp')
```

Any hints on what might (suddenly) be wrong?

Comment: Check this answer.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512592/login-credentials-not-working-with-gmail-smtp)
cheers :)

Comment: I think you can find solution to this problem here.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512592/login-credentials-not-working-with-gmail-smtp)

Comment: @VikramChoudhary this does not apply to my situation. The 'less secure apps' settings is only available for non-2fa-enabled accounts. If you have 2fa you need to use app-specific passwords (which I am using, as described).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, we were blacklisted by Google.

I added my webserver to the IP-Whitelist using this [guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60751?hl=en). After that, mails started working again.

Interestingly enough, even supporters at Google (for a paid Google Workspace account, not free gmail) weren't able to tell me this, I had to experiment myself