# google declined when i try to send email confirmation in django

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, email, smtp

This is the error when I try to send an email confirmation, any help rather than enabling a less secured app thank you
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials kw21-20020a170907771500b00731219a2797sm3559534ejc.210 - SMTP)

Comment: Did you follow the link in the error? Or try a web search for the error?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is no longer supported by Google as of May 30th, 2022. See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en&visit_id=637896899107643254-869975220&p=less-secure-apps&rd=1#zippy=%2Cuse-an-app-password
More info in this thread: [Login credentials not working with Gmail SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512592/login-credentials-not-working-with-gmail-smtp)