# Failed to send message from Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, phpmailer

I tried to send an email from a Laravel controller, but it's showing this error. I'm not using a two step verified Gmail account. Most tutorials use the "enable less secure app" settings, but I can't enable that option in my account.

[image]

this is my env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=******
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=********
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login credentials not working with Gmail SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512592/login-credentials-not-working-with-gmail-smtp)

Comment: Did you follow the steps in [the link included in the error message](https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials)? That gives you clear steps to follow to work around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please use your google app password in MAIL_PASSWORD